# CheckBoxList Binding Error (System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal)

Tags: c#, asp.net, ado.net, webforms

I hope my question is describing itself =) I tried to do everything but I don't seem to get why it's not working!

My CheckBoxList :

```
    <asp:CheckBoxList ID="chkbxlstCuisines" runat="server">
    </asp:CheckBoxList>
```

My code-behind :

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string cuisinesSelectStatement = "SELECT Cuisines.CuisineId, Cuisines.CuisineType FROM Cuisines";


        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConnection"].ConnectionString);
        SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(cuisinesSelectStatement , conn);
        SqlDataReader reader1;

        conn.Open();
        reader1 = comm.ExecuteReader();
        chkbxlstCuisines.DataSource = reader1;
        chkbxlstCuisines.DataBind();

        while (reader1.Read())
        {
            chkbxlstCuisines.DataValueField = reader1["CuisineId"].ToString();
            chkbxlstCuisines.DataTextField = reader1["CuisineType"].ToString();
        }    
            //conn.Close();
    }
```

I hope someone figure it out, I know it's gonna be a little mistake because I fixed this error before but now I really don't know what's wrong!
Thanks in advance guys! =)

**Edit:**

I think the problem is with the casting, because the output is five checkboxes and my database contains exactly five items!

OUTPUT :

```
System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal
System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal
System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal
System.Data.Common.DataRecordInternal
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the "while" code; your code should be:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string cuisinesSelectStatement = "SELECT Cuisines.CuisineId, Cuisines.CuisineType FROM Cuisines";


    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyDbConnection"].ConnectionString);
    SqlCommand comm = new SqlCommand(cuisinesSelectStatement , conn);
    SqlDataReader reader1;
    chkbxlstCuisines.DataValueField = "CuisineId";
    chkbxlstCuisines.DataTextField = "CuisineType";
    conn.Open();
    reader1 = comm.ExecuteReader();
    chkbxlstCuisines.DataSource = reader1;

    chkbxlstCuisines.DataBind();


        //conn.Close();
}
```

DataValueField is the name of the field in your bound object that contains value. 
DataTextField is teh name of teh field in your bound object that contains display text.

Comment: Thanks Andrey, I just figured it out 1 minute before your post but I assigned the DataValueField and DataTextField properties after the binding. I placed them before the connection like you did and it
Works perfect now (Y)

Answer (score 0):

```
                cmd2.CommandText = "select * from upload";
                cmd2.Connection = con1;
                con1.Open();
                GridView1.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                GridView1.DataBind();
                con1.Close();
                cmd2.CommandText = "select * from document1";
                cmd2.Connection = con1;
                con1.Open();
                GridView2.DataSource = cmd2.ExecuteReader();
                GridView2.DataBind();
                con1.Close();
```

Comment: Please explain your answer to help the OP and other users of this site. Code only answers tend to be marked as low quality.